# Rigid bodies broken on all blend files

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I've tried to attach the .blend file, basically no matter what I do, my rigid bodies won't fall anymore.

Here's all the troubleshooting I have done to no avail:

- Cleared cache
- Deleted all baked frame
- Re-Baked
- Made a new project and copied over objects
- Made a completely new project from scratch
- Tried making a simple cube in another project fall (it won't)
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled blender

Cannot find a single post anywhere that offers the correct solution. Please don't ask if I have animated selected -.-

It was working perfectly fine and I was rendering an animation until I cancelled the render and now boom! Nothing works in any version, file or anything.

Please help me, this is for a deadline I can't afford to miss.

Comment: did you try to install another version of blender?

Comment: Can you try a bit harder, to share a minimal failing file, on https://blend-exchange.com/ , please ?   :)

Comment: Without investigating one of your failing files it is unlikely we can help. Maybe you could first tell us what went wrong with trying to attach a blend file, if we could solve this issue we might get a chance to look at the file and find a solution.